# Jupyter Ptyhon3 Kernel freezes when using Spotifies spotipy module

Tags: jupyter-notebook, spotify, spotipy

I am doing a school research project where I do make frequent requests to spotifies server.

I am very confident I'm not hitting the rate limit, and if I were I'm not getting any errors, the kernel just freezes execution on the cell that uses the API to talk to spotify.

[image]

I have to restart the kernel asfter talking to spotify it will wait forever with no error.

It was working, and it has been working on and off.

If I leave my laptop I can run that one cell and it WILL make a single request but then die the next. I'm thinking it may be a resource problem but I'm unsure what to check.

- windows 10
- wsl ubuntu
- Dockerfile

```
FROM jupyter/base-notebook

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=true
EXPOSE 8888

RUN conda install -c potassco clingo pandas spotipy tqdm

RUN echo 'alias_magic clingo script -p "clingo --no-raise-error"' \
    >> `ipython locate profile`/startup/config.ipy

CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--no-browser", "--ip=0.0.0.0"]
```

I tried making requests to Spotify, if I were hitting the rate limit I would expect an error in the request, what ended up happening is the execution froze with the python3 kernel for the notebook.

Comment: Please provide a code block of your code, not (only) an image: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: theres more than just the picture. It's there to show the asterix within the code block of the playbook to show the state it gets stuck in. Although I'm 90% certain the issue I am having is the spotipy module itself. I believe its not throwing an exception when spotify gives you a rate limit and freezes causing the python3 kernel to linger forever.